# Automating weekday function for multiple dates with different permutations

Tags: date, sas, macros, weekday

I need to apply a certain treatment to sas dates depending on what day of the month the 1st of the month falls on. I need this to go forward for a number of months.

I’ve created the following as I also need macro variables for the start and end dates of the month.

```
%let first_dt = '01Jun2020'd;

data _null_
do j =0 to 12;

call Symputx(cats("&monstrt",j),put(intnx("month","first_dt",j,"b"),date9.),'g');
call Symputx(cats("&monend",j),put(intnx("month","first_dt",j,"e"),date9.),'g');

end;
run;
```

I now need to based on the 12 start of the month dates I have, increment the number of days. E.g. if start of month is a Monday I need to increment by 5 days, I’d start of the month is a Tuesday I need to increment by 6 days and so on.

I have attempted the following but it doesn’t appear to be working.

```
%macro weekdays(weekday);

data test;

if weekday("strt&i."d) = &weekday. then 
  new_stdt = put(intnx('day',"strt&i."d,+5),date9.)
;

%mend;
%weekdays(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

Essentially I’m hoping to get all these dates to become populated based off the first_st variable, if this then subsequently changed, I could amend the original value and new values would be populated off of the back of that.

Comment: What is the rule you are trying to implement?  You mentioned Monday and Tuesday but what about other days of the week? Why do want to change based on the day of the week?  What is the meaning of this change of date?  Why are you making macro variables instead of just making a dataset?

Comment: I’m making macro variables as later on in my data process I am going to need to reference these dates within a data step and I’m trying to avoid having to have to hard code every date I have. The other days of the week continue to increment by 1. 

I am able to do this in a dataset by hardcoding the variables, but I’m trying to automate everything as much as I can.

Comment: If you are going to use them in a data step then keeping them in actual variables will be much easier than having to convert the text in the macro variable back into a date value.   You still have not explained what date you want to move to.  For example the first day of MAY 2021 is a weekday 7, Saturday, so what date should that change to?

Comment: May2021 would need to be incremented by 11.

Monday increment by 5, Tuesday 6, Wednesday 7, Thursday 8, Friday 9, Saturday 10, Sunday 11

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that allows you to specify the values the add as a list of 7 numbers.   For example this list matches the values in your comment.

```
%let add=11 5 6 7 8 9 10;
```

Notice how Monday and Tuesday are mapped to the 5 and 6 you mentioned in your question.

So if you have these values:

```
%let first_dt = '01Jun2020'd;
%let offset= 8 ;
```

You can generate a new date value like:

```
%let date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&first_dt,&offset,b));
%let date = %eval(&date + %scan(&add,%sysfunc(weekday(&date))));
```

If you need to have the value of DATE look like something a human would understand you could add.

```
%let date = "%sysfunc(putn(&date,date9.))"d ;
```

So when the month offset is 8 the first of the month is on a Monday so the resulting date is 5 days after the first of the month.

```
1168  %put &=date;
DATE="06FEB2021"d
```

Comment: That makes sense, although can I check where the offset =8 comes from?

Comment: I just use 8 as an example of the fact your original data step was generating 13 months.  Since you did not explain why you were generating 13 months I have no idea what the meaning of it was, but I figured it made more sense to match what you were doing.

Comment: I’ve got this to work, but it is only giving me the result for for the first month. In my original code I had a d loop for looking 12 months forward, is there a way I can get this to calculate for the other months?

Comment: And do what with them?  That is back to the original question of what you are doing and why you are putting dates into macro variables instead of datasets.  If you are doing this inside a macro add a %DO loop around everything to iterate OFFSET from 0 to 11 (or from 1 to 12).

Comment: In a later process I need to call these macros. 

So i will have a step in my dater that looks at the start date and the incremented date for multiple months. 

I thought it would be better to reference something like &date1 which resolves to 09jun2020 rather than having to have various hard coded dates within my code

Comment: To get help converting your code you need show the actual code. If you need to reference 12 dates in a data step then why not just create 12 actual variables with the dates instead of making any macro variables?  data want; set have; if _n_=1 then set dates; array datelist date1-date12 ;  do i=1 to 12;  if thisdate > datelist[i] then ...

Comment: i now have the following..

%macro monthly;
%let first_dt = '01jun2020'd;
%let offset = 8;
%let add = 11 5 6 7 8 9 10;

data test;
%do j=0 %to 12;

%let date = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&first_dt,&offset,b));
%let date = %eval(&date + %scan(&add,%sysfunc(weekday(&date))));
%end;
run;
%mend monthly:
%monthly;
%put date;

WARNING: Apparant symbolic reference DATE not resolved.

Comment: You are looping over J but using OFFSET in the INTNX() call. You are overwriting the same variable named DATE 13 times so you might as well have just started with J (or OFFSET) set to 12.  You are creating DATE as LOCAL to the macro MONTHLY and then trying to reference after MONTHLY has stopped running.  Place the logic that uses the DATE macro variable inside the %DO loop.